# How to make an arrow icon move up and down

Tags: react-native

I want to make an Arrow Icon to move up and down with animation using react native expo. Please any help on how to go about it? this is what I've written so far.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.translation = React.createRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  }

componentDidMount(){
    Animated.timing(this.translation,{
      toValue: 50
    }).start();
 
  }


 <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{translateY: this.translation}],  position: 'absolute', bottom: 50, alignSelf: 'flex-end', paddingRight: 19}}>
          <Entypo name="arrow-bold-down" style={bottomTab.arrow} />
        </Animated.View>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've shared? Are you getting errors, and what are they? If no errors, how does it behave differently than expected?

Comment: you should loop it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to animate infinitely?

```
animate() {
    Animated.timing(this.translation, {
        toValue: 50,
        duration: 500
    }).start(() => {
        Animated.timing(this.translation, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 500
        }).start(() => {
            this.animate()
        })
    })
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.animate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, but its not working and I am getting this warning message ...... [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: animate is not defined]. please help out

Comment: My code will not show the warning. It looks like that you use animate without defining it.